# Where does VS 2022 store the last-used build variant?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2022

As the headline says:

Where does Visual Studio 2022 store the build variant which was last used when building a solution or project?

Background:

Using VS 2022, I have created a simple solution which contains one Windows console project consisting of one `.c` file and one `.h` file. I have compiled the solution / project in the following variant: `x86, Release`.

Then I closed VS 2022 and replicated the solution's directory structure in another folder, excluding the build artifact directories, and copied the source `.c` and `.h` files into the new folder, along with the `.sln`, the `.vcxproj`, the `.vcxproj.filters` and the `.vcxproj.user` files.

I then opened the solution in the new folder in VS 2022 and noticed that it now would build for `x64, Debug`. That means that the last-used build variant must be stored in a file which I didn't copy, outside the files mentioned above. Could somebody please tell me where?

Of course, I could easily change the build variant back with just two mouse clicks. However, there is more to it: I am trying to figure out which files I must put into a Git repository which somebody else can clone to build the software, again using VS 2022. That other person may not know explicitly which variant to build for and therefore must rely on this setting being correct from the beginning on.

This is the new folder before compilation, after having replicated the directory structure and having copied the files as described above (entries ending with `\` denote folders):

```
O:\solution.sln
O:\project\
O:\project\project.vcxproj
O:\project\project.vcxproj.filters
O:\project\project.vcxproj.user
O:\project\main.c
O:\project\main.h
```

When creating the new folder from the original one, I have left out the following folders, assuming that they won't contain relevant data:

```
O:\.vs\
O:\Debug\
O:\Release\
O:\project\Debug\
O:\project\Release\
O:\project\x64\
O:\x64\
```

I couldn't find out yet which file(s) I have to copy in addition to solve the problem. I just hope that it's not the whole `.vs` folder, because that folder can become quite big in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can answer the question myself:

I have found out that the last-used build variant is stored in the `.suo` file. In this case, the `.suo` file is in `.vs\project\v17`.

I originally didn't come to that idea because I always was assuming that a `.suo` file is just a binary form of a `.sln` file, for faster lookup or whatever, and because Microsoft  [recommends against putting it under source control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-user-options-dot-suo-file?view=vs-2022):

> The solution user options (.suo) file contains per-user solution options. This file should not be checked in to source code control.

This advice is exceptionally stupid. As described in the question, if you don't check in that file, and somebody else checks out the solution into a fresh directory and opens it in VS 2022, *his* IDE will revert to build variant `Debug / x64`, regardless of which build variant *you* have used the last time.

[ Side note: Actually, it may not always be `Debug / x64`, but may depend on *his* default settings. But in every case, *your* last-used variant gets lost, or becomes active only because of pure coincidence. ]

This is completely not acceptable, because the other person may not know which target environment the artifacts should be built for. Even worse, the other person may accidentally build and ship debug variants instead of release variants, or vice versa.

This brings us to the question whether there are even more files which we must put under version control so that somebody who checks out the solution into a new directory can build it to obtain a bitwise identical copy of all build artifacts. But that's a matter for a separate post.